# my code is always printing "COMPLETED" and dont exit the while loop

Tags: python

I have a mapreducejob where I define a jobid:

```
jobid = emr.run_jobflow(name="Data Processing"
```

After mapreduce job I want to show a message "Completed Job" when mapreduce job `status == "COMPLETED"`.

Im trying to do this with code below, but Im having always the status like:

STARTING 
STARTING
....
RUNNING
...
COMPLETED 
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
COMPLETED

The problem is that it is always printing "COMPLETED" and dont exit the while loop. And I want to exit so it shows the message "Completed Job".

Do you see where the issue is?

```
status = emr.describe_jobflow(jobid)    

while status.state != 'COMPLETED' or status.state != 'FAILED':      
    status = emr.describe_jobflow(jobid)
    print status.state

print "Job status:" + str(status.state)
print ""
print "Completed Job"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while status.state != 'COMPLETED' or status.state != 'FAILED':
```

This line always evaluates to True. When state is "COMPLETED", it evaluates to `False or True`, which is True. When state is "FAILED", it evaluates to `True or False`, which is True. When state is anything else, it evaluates to `True or True`, which is true. So your loop continues infinitely.

The equivalent of "until A or B" is not "while not A or not B", it's "while not A and not B". See [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more detail.

Replace your `or` with `and`.

```
while status.state != 'COMPLETED' and status.state != 'FAILED':
```